# Solving a differential equation from Cauchy problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am getting acquainted with the Cauchy equations and I am trying to solve this exercise is:

$$\begin{cases} y'=\frac{y^2-4}{x^2+2x+2}\\y(0)=0
\end{cases}$$

I have attempted to solve it in this way:

$$\int \frac{1}{y^2-4} dy= \int \frac{1}{x^2+2x+2}dx$$
$$\frac{1}{4}\log(|y-2|)-\frac{1}{4}\log(|y+2|)=\arctan(x+1)+c$$
$$\frac{1}{4}\log\Big(\frac{|y-2|}{|y+2|}\Big)=\arctan(x+1)+c$$
and from $y(0)=0$ i can write this:
$$\frac{1}{4}\log\Big(\frac{(2-y)}{(y+2)}\Big)=\arctan(x+1)+c$$
$$\frac{2-y}{y+2}=e^{4*arctan(x+1)+4*c}$$
Now, can i isolate the function $y(x)$? Have I done averything correctly up to this point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you are solving the equation around the point $0$. Dropping of absolute value signs is OK in a neighborhood of $0$. You have to find the value of $c$ using the initial condition. You get $c=-\frac {\pi} 4$.  Solving the last equation for $y$ is simple algebra: if you write the equation as $\frac {2-y} {y+2} =g(x)$ then $2-y=(2+y)g(x)$ which gives $y=\frac {2 -2g(x)} {1+g(x)}$.

Comment: Two further remarks about the initial post. The line with the quotient of logarithms is wrong. (Typo?) Also you can explicitly compute the constant $c$.

Comment: @maxmilgram I ignored the mistake about writing quotient of logarithms because it looks like  typo. I have included the value of $c$ in my answer.

Comment: Yes @maxmilgram, you are right. I correct the quotient.

Comment: @andrew Use the third line from bottom in your answer, You will get $c$ easily.